# Error running Java project with Gradle -- Looking for wrong Java version

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Java project in Intellij IDEA and am using Gradle as a build tool. For whatever reason, when I try to run the project, I am getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-12.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

My current version of Java is 1.8. I made sure my JAVA_HOME was set to the 1.8 location. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellij and Gradle is little bit tricky:

1. You can run from console\terminal
2. Also you can run with Intellij UI (aka "play" button)

If you are using UI make sure your setup is correct for the gradle:

On Mac (Similar to Windows):
**Intellij** -> **Preferences**, go to: **Build, Execution, Deployment** -> **Build Tools** -> **Gradle** [image: Preferences]

Make sure:
1. Your **Gradle JVM** is pointing to current place
2. (Optional) Make sure you are using correct gradle/wrapper/etc

Comment: So my Gradle JVM is pointing to the wrong place, but the only options in the drop down are for Java 11. How do I add the correct Gradle JVM for 1.8? And also, what exactly is the Specified Location? Like what sort of path should I be looking for there?

Comment: Or maybe a better question would be is if Intellij and Gradle are tricky working together, is there a better IDE that you would recommend to use with Gradle?

Comment: Actually, I figured out my Java 1.8 JVM was pointing to the wrong directory. I fixed that and made sure that all projects point to that directory and so does Gradle. I completely removed any Java 11 or 12 JVMs from IntelliJ and it is still looking for the JVM 12 folder for some reason.